# Redirect page if window.history.back isn't possible

Tags: javascript, redirect, browser

I've been using the browser history to go back pages. However since JS can't read the users history reliably, when there is no history I have no way of knowing that my button is no longer working.

I have tried using something along these lines to redirect the page if the back fails:

```
window.history.back();
setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"; }, 500);
```

However this completely relies on the arbitrary time period which may or may not work for all users (and setting it high enough to guarantee it work for everyone will provide a painfully slow experience for the majority of people)

Suggested in a comment I have now also tried using some various attempts along these lines:

```
if (!window.history.back()) { 
    window.location.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
}
```

However `window.history.back()` will always return `false` whether or not the function is successful. I presume this is a security feature built into browsers.

Does anyone know of a way to either detect the failed page change, or another way this issue could be solved in a more elegant way?

Comment: if(!window.history.back()){
  window.location.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
}

Comment: @CashLee李秉骏 That works perfectly in Chrome and IE, but seems to always redirect in Firefox and Safari whether there's history or not.

Comment: Emm...you can console window.history object in the browsers' debugger.I just try to console window.history in Safari.I found Safari use window.history.location to manage.So in Safari you can use if(window.history.location){...} to check.

Comment: I've been looking further into it, and actually the neither of those options work in any of the browsers (It just happened to be executing fast enough for me not to see the contents of the IF in some browsers) `window.history.back()` always returns `false` whether it succeeds or not (Presumably for security reasons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with a relatively useful (if a bit hacky) solution:

```
// On page load
if (history.length <= 1) { 
    /* 
    *  This will only execute the first time the page (with absolutely no browser
    *  history, including browser splash screens that may add to the history) 
    *  is loaded, it wont happen if you navigate back to the page
    *  so store the current page in local storage
    */
    localStorage.setItem("root", document.location);
}
// Then execute some code only on the root
if (localStorage.getItem("root") == document.location) {
    // Your code
}
```

Some potential issues:

- If you need multiple pages of this type open at once, it will break since the first instance of the pages loaded will be checking for the root of the second (unless you customise the local storage name to that group of pages)
- It requires [local storage which doesn't work on some of the (really) old browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage)
- This will only work for pages with **no** browser history, generally these only occur when opening a page in a new tab or clicking a link in an external application/desktop. Most browsers include a splash-screen/home-page which will add to the browser history.